# What are the joint and marginals in this neural network paper?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04062.pdf) has an algorithm which draws from the joint and then from the marginal. What does this actually mean in the code?

Is the joint an (x,y) training pair? Then what is the marginal?

[image]

Comment: Let $f(x,z) = z$. It is about the distribution of $(X,Z)$ and the distribution of $f(X,Z)$